# Dreamweaver alternative

Tags: ide, dreamweaver, html-editor, css-editor

I'm aware there are plenty of questions like this but I'm looking to move to another development environment but not lose some of the better Dreamweaver features / behaviors.

I have Dreamweaver CS6 and it just gets worse every release. The simple act of opening a file causes it to freeze these days.

Here are the features I'd like in the alternative. I code in "code view" but design view is very useful to paste and format body copy.

- Tag auto close. But only when I type "</"
- Related files (file browser might do)
- Node tree, so I can click on a node which will be highlighted in the source code.
- Good source code autocomplete, highlighting, auto formatting etc
- Decent "design" area that I can paste in the text content, hitting enter creates a p, hitting tab creates a list, hitting tab in an existing list creates a nested list, options to keep various levels of formatting on content pasted from another source etc

Comment: If you're looking for something that's like Dreamweaver I'd suggest an earlier version of it.

Comment: In addition I think Sublime Text is the hottest editor among web coders currently, it's a good piece of software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I can continue to use DW CS6. If you happen to be linking to hosted JS or CSS files, DW will spend far too much time downloading them.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Dreamweaver CS6\Remote Download]
"RemoteDownloadAllow"="FALSE"
```

Answer (score 3):

Aptana Studio 3 - free, fast, clean

Answer (score 2):

A good, free alternative is Brackets (http://brackets.io/).