# Recommendations for open source alternatives to Dreamweaver for web development

Tags: open-source, dreamweaver, html-editor, code-editor, css-editor

I'm on the hunt for an open-source version of Adobe Dreamweaver to use for my freelance web development projects. I'm primarily a source coder, but I would find a split or visual view for CSS and design work, as well as native FTP functionality, helpful. My work involves HTML, CSS, JavaScript/jQuery, and ColdFusion. Native support for the latter, in particular, would be ideal.

I've come across the following programs that seem somewhat promising:

- [BlueGriffin](http://bluegriffon.org/) (last stable version is dated June 19, 2013)
- [Brackets](http://brackets.io/?lang=en)
- [CoffeeCup HTML Editor](http://www.coffeecup.com/free-editor/)

A quick search here in the StackOverflow community turned up a couple of similar questions (see [Dreamweaver alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567706/dreamweaver-alternative) and [Any open source alternatives for Dreamweaver using WebDav?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975625/any-open-source-alternatives-for-dreamweaver-using-webdav)), but I would appreciate more recent/modern alternatives.

I'm a Windows user running 8.1.

I'd love to know what others more experienced than me in this quest have uncovered.

Comment: It's sad when people downvote questions useful to the community based on technicalia

Comment: @ТаняТ. - or close useful questions as off-topic.  Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide an update and answer to my question, I've found Brackets to be superior thus far. The editor is nifty in and of itself, but there's an absolute treasure trove of extensions to behold. For my specific needs, I found [FTP-Sync](https://github.com/timburgess/brackets-ftp-sync) and [cfBrackets](http://cfbrackets.org) exceptionally helpful. They installed neatly and effortlessly.

Comment: Which ones you've evaluated?

Comment: cfBrackets has been quite nice, as it adds support for ColdFusion tags per release version (CF 9, CF 10, etc.). I've not yet found a satisfactory FTP plug-in for my purposes; FTP-Sync is meant to synchronize an entire directory vs. individual files. I'll post back with further research, if folks wish it.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse with the CFEclipse plugin , or CFBuilder (yes there is a free version)

Comment: Jim, thanks for your answer. Both CFEclipse and CFBuilder are useful tools, but a bit overkill for my needs (I don't need a server on my machine; just a program that recognizes and provides support for CF).